# Why can't I parse this json? And how do I include a json data file in my index.html?

Tags: json, parsing

This is my first time learning json and this is my sample code:

```
$(function () {
        var obj = jQuery.
        parseJSON('{"Plan":[{"PlanId":1,
        "PlanName":"spl Small Win 32 bit - Fixed",
        "OS":"Windows 2003 Standard, 32-bit"}]}');
        console.log(obj.Plan);                      
});
```

I get an error in my console that says: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL.
What is wrong with this data? Am I parsing it wrong?

Also I have a Json file with some sample data in it (the above data is a snippet of it). How do I include it in my project? Do I use script tags?

Comment: Strings cannot span multiple lines in JavaScript. This is not related to your JSON string, the code is not even executed, the JavaScript parser cannot read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are spanning the command to a new line, plus, the multiple lines are causing your problem. Try

```
$(function () {
  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"Plan":[{"PlanId":1,'+
    '"PlanName":"spl Small Win 32 bit - Fixed",'+
    '"OS":"Windows 2003 Standard, 32-bit"}]}');
  console.log(obj.Plan);                      
});
```

Comment: Hey this worked! did not know I needed to keep everything in one line. Any idea how I include an entire file of this kind of data in my project?

Comment: It's called Plans.json btw. How do I use it?

Comment: If the data in the file is JSON formatted, you can simply use an ajax request: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: If you don't want a separate request to load the file, and want the data embedded in the first response content, it would look like this:
`var obj = ...json.data.embedded.right.here...   ;`